# Codeigniter: Add Hook in model

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

Simple question.
How do i add a post_system hook within a module using Codeigniter framework?

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: can you explain your functionality why you want to use hook !!!!!

Comment: I want to run a function after user creation. This function takes about 10 secounds to finish, and there is no need for the user to wait that long.

Comment: A hook will take up user time anyway, it doesn't run as a separate process, if what you're doing is really important then the user should wait the 10 seconds, otherwise use a cron & process queued users.

Comment: A post_system hook will send everything to the browser, THEN load the function. And its not important for the user to see the result i generate.

Comment: This may be the case, but ahmad is actually right. The output is pushed to the browser, but only if you use the codeigniter output core class and the page will still seem to load after you run the hook. The hook itself is not asynchronous, but the browser may start rendering beforehand. What i am wondering is: maybe there is a way to speed up the 10s  function? Because that seems like an absurd amount of time for any function. Do you have more info on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in dynamic hooking post by dazoe in the codeigniter wiki on github:
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Dynamic-Hooking

Here they show you how to extend the Hooks class with a MY_Hooks instance and inside that class is a function `add_hook($hookwhere, $hook)` to add this dynamically.

Another approach would be to use the core output class and then flush the output to the browser before running your 10s function.

Hope this helps, but i think you need to look at ways you can speed up the 10s function.